# Undefined class constant error in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a problem here. I set a constant, like this:

```
/** @const HOLIDAYS_PER_WORK_DAY Earned holidays per one working day. */
const HOLIDAYS_PER_WORK_DAY = 0.4;
```

And I'm trying to count holiday days, by:

```
$holidays = 'floor(datediff(curdate(), employment_date) * ' . Employee::HOLIDAYS_PER__WORK_DAY . ')';
```

And it says `Undefined class constant 'HOLIDAYS_PER__WORK_DAY'`. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in `HOLIDAYS_PER__WORK_DAY`, you put 2 `__` right after `PER`, it should be `Employee::HOLIDAYS_PER_WORK_DAY`.

I strongly recommend you using an IDE like PhpStorm or Netbeans, those things won't happen to you.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans and it just happened anyway. Nevermind, thank you for solving that :)

Comment: I use PhpStorm and it would highlight an inexistent class variable and/or method. I guessed netbeans does the same, but I do not use it. Switch to PhPstorm then dude ;)